# Capture screenshot in GenyMotion

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I am using **Genymotion** for running android application.
Could any one tell me how to capture screen shot in **[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)** ?

Comment: Please, don't forget to select an answer! ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*Disclaimer : I'm part of the same company as the Genymotion team.*

This feature is included in the product. It is one of the paid feature of the screencast widget. [Look at the pricing page here](https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc).

Two ways to access it:

- pay for the pro or indie licence
- use the trial version, it offers you the indie features. **Be careful**, there is only one trial day left :-/

Once your VM is started, open the screencast widget

[image]

Then take a picture with the dedicated button

[image]

**UPDATE:** You have bellow another ways to take a screenshot using [Android Device Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771416/capture-screenshot-in-genymotion/23092701#23092701) or the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316765/1466415)

Comment: Thanks dya. Usually, on StackOverflow, if an answer solve your problem you have to mark it as resolved instead of upvote like you did.

Comment: Where do you find the screenshot ? The location of the screenshot. Specifically on linux

Answer (score 193):

If you are using Android Studio or Eclipse, you can just click the button "Screen Capture" in the Android DDMS:

[image]

Comment: This also works in Eclipse and not only in Android Studio. Just switch to DDMS and click on the camera symbol with the right device selected.

Comment: This won't work for 2.3.7 devices on Genymotion as there is currently a bug in their framebufer implementation. Just FYI.

Comment: Is there any shortcut for this?

Comment: if it shows error that can't connect to device just restart Android Studio :)

Answer (score 52):

You can use adb to get the screenshot from command line:

```
adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png
```

This article has the details:
http://blog.shvetsov.com/2013/02/grab-android-screenshot-to-computer-via.html

To make my life easier, I made an alias in .bash_profile:

```
alias screenshot="adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > ~/Downloads/android_screenshot.png"
```

Now I can type `screenshot` in Terminal and get a screenshot of currently running emulator in my Downloads directory.

Comment: On a Mac I was getting `adb server is out of date.  killing...` errors when trying this. I fixed it by using the `adb` included in Genymotion: `/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > ~/Downloads/android_screenshot.png`

Comment: Nice! Works great!

Comment: cool so i dont need to upgrade my genymotion license  :cry: !

Comment: This is a PRO level answer, thanks! Just as an update, on Mac OSX it currently works with the command:

    alias screenshot="adb shell screencap -p > ~/Downloads/android_screenshot.png"

Comment: I prefer to make the name unique by adding the timestamp: alias screenshot='/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > ~/Desktop/Android_Screenshot_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M"-%S).png'

Answer (score 24):

Use this commands:

- Windows:

  ```
  C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb shell screencap -p "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" && C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb pull "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" "C:\output.png" && C:\"Program Files"\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb shell rm "/mnt/sdcard/output.png"
  ```

  - Note: Make sure you have permission to write to `C:\output.png`; otherwise, change it to whatever path you like.
- OS X:

  ```
  /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > ~/Desktop/Android_Screenshot_$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S).png
  ```

Comment: With slight modifications, it is working for me: `adb shell screencap -p "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" && adb pull "/mnt/sdcard/output.png" . && adb shell rm "/mnt/sdcard/output.png"`

Comment: I believe a normal user on Windows doesn't have the permissions to write directly to "C:\", so you better change the target location of the `adb pull` to a directory where you really have write rights, to ensure this works. Otherwise pretty simple and elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @SaAtomic, I have edited my answer with a note.

Comment: `error: cannot connect to daemon: cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:5037 (10061)`

Answer (score 13):

1. Select genymotion simulator
2. Hit shortcut key describe below

   - Windows : Ctrl+Shift+S
   - Mac     : Cmd+Shift+S
3. You can find your screenshots at desktop

Comment: It works but screenshot cannot saved in desktop. It saved in C:/Users/~LoginName~/~AVD Name~/Screenshot-datetimestamp.png

Comment: For mac it depends on your screenshot folder path, default is desktop

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It works even with free version of Genymotion 2.8.0 (Windows) :)

Answer (score 11):

I think you can also take videos for free. Genymotion uses VirtualBox to do almost all the heavy lifting, so you should open VirtualBox and look at what you can do in it.

You will find options in Virtualbox to capture video!
[image]

Comment: I opened `Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager` on Windows 7 and it looks nothing like yours...

Comment: I just installed VirtualBox on Win7 and it looks like this for me. http://i.imgur.com/XKqlFW2.jpg

Comment: That's a "linux", do you have the same options for Genymotion Androids? (Maybe it only works above Android 4, I tried 2.3.7)

Comment: have you tried this? For VirtualBox on debian, it only records the Android devices kernel messages.

Comment: You cannot start a genymotion device directly from virtualBox. This solution doesn't works.

Answer (score 8):

> adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png

Answer (score 5):

If your Mac is slow and you hate running Eclipse and the emulator together here is a quicker way.

1. Export your apk.
2. Start Genymotion.
3. Drag the apk to the emulator, in order to install it.
4. Go to 'android-sdk-macosx>tools>ddms'.
5. Run that file.
6. A new instance of ddms will be started. Unlike Eclipse, it doesn't slow down your system.
7. Use the 'Menu>Device>Screenshot' option to take screenshot.

This is a good option for those using slow computers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eclipse, then follow the steps for any type of emulator: 
1. Select DDMS
2. In Devices window of DDMS select Genymotion device
3. Click on Camera icon then save it to specific location.
[image: In Devices window just click on Camera icon. I already mark it by circle here]

Answer (score 2):

For Linux and Windows (I used gitbash on windows)

`adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/\r$//' > screen.png`

For Mac

`adb shell screencap -p | perl -pe 's/\x0D\x0A/\x0A/g' > screen.png`

Answer (score 0):

@Reck says there's a bug in the Genymotion implementation so we can't take screenshots on 2.3.7. This means that Android Studio / DDMS can't get the proper pixels. `adb shell screencap` says there's no `screencap` command.

Assuming you have access to the code you can simply call this method:

```
public static void screenshot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    view.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    try {
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        storageDir.mkdirs();
        File file = File.createTempFile(timeStamp, ".png", storageDir);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, new FileOutputStream(file));
        Log.i("SCREENSHOT", "adb pull " + file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("SCREENSHOT", "Cannot save screenshot of " + view, e);
    }
}
```

In Activity:

```
screenshot(getWindow().getDecorView());
```

In Fragment:

```
screenshot(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView());
```

The only limitation I know is that it won't include the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Mac, sometimes CMD + Shift + 4 (screenshot of a selected portion in OSX ) and then selecting the simulator region is enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot

On many Android devices, you can capture a screenshot with a key-combination: Simultaneously press-and-hold Power and Volume-down. You can also capture a screenshot with Android Studio as follows:

Run your app on a connected device or emulator. If using a connected device, be sure you have enabled USB debugging.
In Android Studio, select View > Tool Windows > Logcat to open Logcat.
Select the device and a process from the drop-down at the top of the window.
Click Screen Capture   on the left side of the window.
The screenshot appears in a Screenshot Editor window

It Works for even Genymotion Emulator

[Check here for further information](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot)